# Uploading images to server doesn't work

Tags: php, ios, xcode, image, upload

I'm trying to upload pictures to my server via php request in xcode. I tried many possibilities but as of now nothing seems to work. I'm not that well acquainted with php, so maybe there lies the error. Right now it is just giving me the errors "Incorrect file type", but I'm definitely using a jpg image. (Tried it with more than once)

Here is what I have in xcode:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, 90);
NSString *urlString = @"http://myserver/upload.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and my php file:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/images/';      //Uploading to same directory as PHP file
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))
{
echo "Temp file uploaded. \r\n";
} else {
echo "Temp file not uploaded. \r\n";
}

if ((!($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == "image/jpeg")) && (!($_FILES['userfile']['type']    == "image/png")))           
{
exit("Incorrect file type.  " . $_FILES['userfile']['type'] . " is the file type you     uploaded."); 
}


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    $postsize = ini_get('post_max_size');   
    $canupload = ini_get('file_uploads');    
    $tempdir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');   
    $maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    echo "http://www.mycompanyname.com/myappname/{$file}" . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['size'] . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['type'] ;
}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check file types and also check directory path $uploaddir = '/images/'; is it correct? this code is working fine for me.

Comment: It is? Now that is interesting, why isn't it working for me then? Yes, directory is correct, definitely!

Comment: I just change directory name and its going work, remove 1st slash.

Comment: I did, he still tells me incorrect file type. Tried it with various pictures now, all ending in either jpg or png.

Comment: "Temp file not uploaded. 
Incorrect file type.   is the file type you uploaded."

Comment: [Check I have uploaded](http://jobrevolver.com/clients/php/file/file.php) [Check Uploaded images](http://jobrevolver.com/clients/php/file/listimages.php)

Comment: Thanks I do the same. Using it like this works fine for me aswell. But as soon as I try to upload a picture from my iPhone I get the errors.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. When I upload it via iphone it mistakes the file for something else than an image.

Comment: yes exactly, you have to check it, for testing you can remove all conditions of if else then figure it out what actually passing from your code... you can use print file and check it.

Comment: Thanks, I did a follow up question to it. You are more than welcome to take a look at it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351015/uploading-an-image-to-a-server-through-imagepicker-doesnt-work-need-solution

Answer (score 1):

> $_FILES['userfile']['type'] The mime type of the file, if the browser
>   provided this information. An example would be "image/gif". This mime
>   type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take
>   its value for granted.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

If you want to check mime-type you should follow another way such as [mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mime-content-type.php)